# Computing the integral $\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\cos^2(x) \exp(\cos^2(x))dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I am doing some work on graphs, and came across calculating an integral like this:
$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\cos^2(x) \exp(\cos^2(x))dx$. By replacing $\tan(x)=t$, I reduced the problem to calculating the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1+t^2)^2} \exp(\frac{1}{(1+t^2)})dt$. Do you have any idea how to calculate it quickly?

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. That's an interesting integral. Could you please explain your substitution in a bit more detail?

Comment: $tg(x)=t$ , $x=arctg(t)$, $cos(x) = cos(arctg(t)) = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt(1+t^2)}$, $dx = \dfrac{dt}{1+t^2}$. Substituting it all into the original expression have $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1+t^2)^2} \exp(\frac{1}{(1+t^2)})dt$

Answer (score 1):

Mathematica says:

$\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{e}\pi\left(I_0\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+I_1\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)$

For the original integral.

Since the [definition of the Bessel function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) $I$ is close to your integral, I don't think there is much to add.